# How to disable Admin account and create new account

Tags: windows, passwords

I have administrator account named `syspan` and my product main service is configured by this account. 
Here my question: can I disable this account and define a new administrator account with the same privileges and GROUP participation as the default ADMINISTATOR account, without adversely affecting the product??

To do this I will follow these steps which I believe generic to all type of OS.

```
Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Computer Management -> Local Users Groups -> 
Users -> Select syspan -> Rightclick properties and disable it.
```

And then create new account like this way :

```
Control panel -> Administrative tools -> Computer Management -> Local Users Groups -> 
Users -> New user and add it in to Administrators group in Groups also.
```

And I will change services to this account, password, confirm password also.

Is this the right way to achieve it?

Comment: Why not just keep your old account active?

Comment: i didnot get you completely. Here i wanted to do test by disabling first account and creating new account,,Do we need to keep old account active all time

Comment: ah, got it. Are there services that are running as syspan?

Comment: yes soandos ,main service is running with syspan account

Comment: So it will also need to be added to the new user.

Comment: i didnot get you,after disabling first account i am creating new account like that only,in my question i have pointed that one

Comment: @soandos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/650/discussion-between-peter-and-soandos)